# How to get all the factors of a number using its prime factorization?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, factoring, prime-factorization

For example, I have the number $420$. This can be broken down into its prime factorization of $$2^2 \times3^1\times5^1\times7^1 = 420 $$

Using $$\prod_{i=1}^r (a_r + 1)$$ where $a$ is the magnitude of the power a prime factor is raised by and $r$ is the number of prime factors. I get $24$ possible factors.

Is there an easy way to iterate through all those $4$ factors to obtain all $24$? I know this can be easily done using a table with numbers with only $2$ factors. But, as this one has $4$ I obviously can't implement the table method. So any general solution to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Does $2^3$ really divide $420$?

Comment: Whoops, that's supposed to be a $2^2$ thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Don't you mean $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^r (a_r+1)$ ? I also got 32 possible factors by $4(2)(2)(2)$. it's 30 if you get rid of the trivial ones

Comment: It's not 32, I just put the wrong power for 2, it's definitely 24. Sorry!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By way of example of a table of factors, just to check we're talking about the same thing:

The factors of $8=2^3$ are of course just $2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3$ or calculated out  $1,2,4,8$.

The factors of $9=3^2$ are  $3^0, 3^1, 3^2$ aka $1,3,9$.

Now the factors of $72$ can be made up by combining two numbers chosen, one from each of these two sets:

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\times & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\
3 & 3 & 6 & 12 & 24 \\
9 & 9 & 18 & 36 & 72 \\
\end{array}

This is no doubt the kind of table you are thinking of.

For $420$ we could apply this process repeatedly, just feeding the contents of each table into one axis of the next table:

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\times & 1 & 2 & 4  \\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 4  \\
3 & 3 & 6 & 12 \\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\times & 1 & 2 & 4   & 3 & 6 & 12 \\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 4  & 3 & 6 & 12 \\
5 & 5 & 10 & 20 & 15 & 30 & 60  \\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\times & 1 & 2 & 4  & 3 & 6 & 12 & 5 & 10 & 20 & 15 & 30 & 60 \\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 12 & 5 & 10 & 20 & 15 & 30 & 60\\
7 & 7 & 14 & 28 & 21 & 42 & 84 & 35 & 70 & 140 & 105 & 210 & 420\\
\end{array}

or for a slightly more attractive final table we could split the factors into more equal subsets, here the factors of $2^23^1 =12$ across the top and the factors of $5^17^1=35$ down the side.

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\times & 1 & 2 & 4  & 3 & 6 & 12 \\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 12 \\
5 & 5 & 10 & 20 & 15 & 30 & 60\\
7 & 7 & 14 & 28 & 21 & 42 & 84 \\
35 & 35 & 70 & 140 & 105 & 210 & 420\\
\end{array}

Comment: Wow! This was exactly what I was looking for, that's so cool!

Comment: Or we can put the table in n-dimensional space, where n is the number of distinct prime factors.

Comment: @Acccumulation I couldn't get the 4-dimensional formatting to work :-)

Comment: @Joffan You can simulate the 4D formatting by using a 2D table of 2D tables, like \begin{array}{ccccc|ccc}
 &  &  & 1 &  &  & 5\\
 &  &  &  & \\
1 &  & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 10 & 20\\
 &  & 3 & 6 & 12 & 15 & 30 & 60\\
\hline 7 &  & 7 & 14 & 28 & 35 & 70 & 140\\
 &  & 21 & 42 & 84 & 105 & 210 & 420
\end{array}

Comment: hmmm... I personally prefer the "odometer" reading.  Factor is $n = 2^a3^b5^c7^d$ so just list out all the $(d,c,b,a)$ as they roll out on an odometer.  $(0,0,0,0)$  $(0,0,0,1)$, $(0,0,0,2)$, $(0,0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1,1)$,$(0,0,1,2)$, $(0,1,0,0)$, etc.... so $(1,0,1, 2)$ for instance would be $7^1*5^0*3^1*2^2 = 7*3*4 = 84$.  That way I wouldn't need my 4-dimensional table formating.

Comment: @fleablood yes, that's how I'd do the general case in procedural-style code to avoid unknown-level nested loops - list of primes, list of multiplicities, step through.

Answer (score 18):

Expand the following expression:
$$(2^0+2^1+2^2)(3^0+3^1)(5^0+5^1)(7^0+7^1)$$
Each combination of four choices (e.g. $2^2, 3^1, 5^0, 7^1$, whose product is $2^23^15^07^1=84$) gives a distinct factor of $420$.

Comment: So out of those 84 only 24 of them are unqiue? Is this really the simplest way of finding all the factors? That's so much distributing and elinimating duplicates.

Comment: $84$ is one of the $24$ divisors.  All $24$ divisors are unique.

Comment: Oh I get it! That's really cool :)

Answer (score 7):

Well... yeah.  They are all the numbers that are in the form $2^a3^b5^c7^d$ where $0 \le a \le 2; 0 \le b\le 1; 0 \le c\le 1;0 \le d\le 1;$

Just list them all:

$2^03^05^07^0 = 1$

$2^13^05^07^0 = 2$

$2^23^05^07^0 = 4$

$2^03^15^07^0 =3$

$2^13^15^07^0 =6$

....etc...

Less typing: they are $1,2,4,3,6,12,5,10,20,15,30,60,7,14,28,21,42,84,35,70,140,105,210,420$

In general if $N=\prod p_i^{k_i}$ just list every possible $\prod p_i^{m_i}$ where for each $m_i$ $0\le m_i \le k_i$.

Comment: Notice that the exponents form a [mixed radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) number that is repeatedly incremented (by $1$) with radices (left-to-right) 3, 2, 2, 2.  It's a little weird to increment on the left and carry to the right, but that could be fixed in several ways.

Comment: In an earlier edit I first listed from right to left (first the 7, then the 5, and the twos last).  But I think going from left to right seemed more natural as we are doing the generally smaller terms first.  Also I prefer "rolling " through the terms with the highest powers first.  But frankly I really don't think it matters.  Does it?

Comment: The increment is easier to pick out of the visual noise (all the non-superscripts) if it is $0000, 0001, 0002, 0010, \dots$.  It's not necessary, but it may well be clearer.

Comment: I was hoping that would be clear.  But without the "visual noise" I don't know if someone would see or understand that 0000=1,0001=2,0002=4,0010=3 etc.

Answer (score 4):

If
$n = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{a_i}
$
is the prime factorization on $n$,
there are
$\prod_{i=1}^r (a_i + 1)
$
prime factors.

Look at this
as counting a
$r$-digit number in a variable base,
with the base of the
$i$-th digit being
$a_i+1$,
so that digit goes from
$0$ to $a_i$.
If
$b_i$ is the $i$-th digit,
then the value corresponding
to that digit is
$p_i^{b_i}$.

Here is my take
on a moderately efficient algorithm
to compute all the 
possible factors.
The divisor starts at $1$.
When a digit is incremented,
the value of the divisor
is multiplied by $p_i$.
If the $i$-th digit
exceeds $a_i$,
it is set to zero,
the divisor divided by
$p_i^{a_i}$,
and the next digit is examined.

Initialize
$d = 1$
(the divisor)
and
$b_i = 0$
and
$c_i = p_i^{a_i}$
for $i=1$ to $r$
(the exponents and max powers of $p_i$).

$\text{do forever}\\
\quad\text{output } d\\
\quad\text{for }i=1\text{ to }r\\
\qquad \text{if } b_i<a_i\text{ then } b_i=b_i+1; d=d\cdot p_i; \text{ exit for loop}
\quad\text{(digit did not overflow)}\\
\qquad\text{else } b_i=0; d=d/c_i
\quad\text{(digit overflowed - reset and look at next digit)}\\
\quad\text{end for}\\
\quad\text{if }d=1\text{ then exit do loop}
\quad\text{(all digits overflowed - done)}\\
\text{end do}\\
$